# NotFittedError: Estimator not fitted, call `fit` before exploiting the model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am running Python 3.5.2 on a Macbook OSX 10.2.1 (Sierra).

While attempting to run some code for the Titanic Dataset from Kaggle, I keep getting the following error:

> ---
>
> NotFittedError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         6 
>         7 # Make your prediction using the test set and print them.
>   ----> 8 my_prediction = my_tree_one.predict(test_features)
>         9 print(my_prediction)
>        10
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/tree/tree.py
>   in predict(self, X, check_input)
>       429         """
>       430 
>   --> 431         X = self._validate_X_predict(X, check_input)
>       432         proba = self.tree_.predict(X)
>       433         n_samples = X.shape[0]
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/tree/tree.py
>   in _validate_X_predict(self, X, check_input)
>       386         """Validate X whenever one tries to predict, apply, predict_proba"""
>       387         if self.tree_ is None:
>   --> 388             raise NotFittedError("Estimator not fitted, "
>       389                                  "call `fit` before exploiting the model.")
>       390
>
> NotFittedError: Estimator not fitted, call `fit` before exploiting the
>   model.

The offending code seems to be this:

```
# Impute the missing value with the median
test.Fare[152] = test.Fare.median()

# Extract the features from the test set: Pclass, Sex, Age, and Fare.
test_features = test[["Pclass", "Sex", "Age", "Fare"]].values

# Make your prediction using the test set and print them.
my_prediction = my_tree_one.predict(test_features)
print(my_prediction)

# Create a data frame with two columns: PassengerId & Survived. Survived contains your predictions
PassengerId =np.array(test["PassengerId"]).astype(int)
my_solution = pd.DataFrame(my_prediction, PassengerId, columns = ["Survived"])
print(my_solution)

# Check that your data frame has 418 entries
print(my_solution.shape)

# Write your solution to a csv file with the name my_solution.csv
my_solution.to_csv("my_solution_one.csv", index_label = ["PassengerId"])
```

And here is a link to the rest of the [code](https://gist.github.com/jarasandh/8df831a4d5c908888e9eb8a2e3851546).

Since I already have called the 'fit' function, I cannot understand this error message. Where am I going wrong? Thanks for your time.

**Edit**:
Turns out that the problem is inherited from the previous block of code.

```
# Fit your first decision tree: my_tree_one
my_tree_one = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
my_tree_one = my_tree_one.fit(features_one, target)

# Look at the importance and score of the included features
print(my_tree_one.feature_importances_)
print(my_tree_one.score(features_one, target))
```

With the line:
**my_tree_one = my_tree_one.fit(features_one, target)**

generating the error:

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for
>   dtype('float32').

Comment: Are you running the whole file https://gist.github.com/jarasandh/8df831a4d5c908888e9eb8a2e3851546 directly? It looks like an error you get while playing with the interactive interpreter.

Comment: Yes indeed. And turns out that error is due to the previous block of code. Just updating the original post with the new findings.

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory: either the `features_one` or the `target` arrays do contain `NaN`s or infinite values, so the estimator fails to fit and therefore you cannot use it for prediction later.

Check those arrays and treat `NaN` values accordingly before fitting.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the new library package that has the issue. I also faced the same issue in the lgbm package and tried with respective lower version package and it got resolved.

**You can try with below command for your correct version package installation**

```
pip install libraryName==x.x.x
```

or

```
pip3 install libraryName==x.x.x
```